# How to enumerate nodes and relationships along path returned via Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I opened this question here: [How to find specific subgraph in Neo4j using where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867426/how-to-find-specific-subgraph-in-neo4j-using-where-clause) to find a path of a certain criteria.  Yet when I try to do things like get the relationship type I cannot.

For example I tried `MATCH p = (n:Root)-[rs1*]->()
WHERE ALL(rel in rs1 WHERE rel.relevance is null)
RETURN nodes(p), TYPE(relationships(p))`

But I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was Collection<Relationship>
```

I think I need to use a `WITH` clause but not sure.

Similarly I wanted the ID of a node but that also failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `relationships` returns a collection and the `type` function only works on a single relationship. There are two main approaches to solve this.

Use [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-unwind) to get a separate row for each relationship:

```
MATCH p = (n:Root)-[rs1*]->()
WHERE ALL(rel in rs1 WHERE rel.relevance is null)
WITH relationships(p) AS rs
UNWIND n, rs AS r
RETURN n, type(r)
```

Use [`extract`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-extract) to get the results in a list (in a single row per root node):

```
MATCH p = (n:Root)-[rs1*]->()
WHERE ALL(rel in rs1 WHERE rel.relevance is null)
WITH n, relationships(p) AS rs
RETURN n, extract(r IN rs | type(r))
```

Or even shorter:

```
MATCH p = (n:Root)-[rs1*]->()
WHERE ALL(rel in rs1 WHERE rel.relevance is null)
RETURN n, extract(r IN relationships(p) | type(r))
```